# How to insert task list as web art in SharePoint Modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, task-list, modern-pages

I have a site where a large number of task lists are present. I want to display those task list as webpart in different modern page.Please let me know if it is feasible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, there is no plan for modernizing task list and list web part is not able to display task list. You may need to use a classic page to display them.

You can vote [here](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/31844641-modern-experience-for-task-lists).

If you really need to do this, you can use the embed web part to embed the URL of the task list. It does not look nice but will work.